# How to get a screen resize dimension from a service in angular 2+?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services, screen-size

***First this not duplicated take time to read, because there is lot of similar question but they are in the @Component decorator***

I got the idea to catch screen resizing in a service then sharing some css value by an observable, but it seem that my service is not working (not able  to catch screen resize event).

**Here is my code**

```
import { Injectable, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BreakPointService {

    normal: {
        background: 'w3-teal',
        inputColor: 'w3-light-grey',
        css_parent: 'w3-container w3-teal'
    };
    breakpoint: {
        background: 'w3-dark-blue',
        inputColor: 'w3-white',
        css_parent: 'w3-container w3-light-grey'
    };
    breakPointValue: number;


    css_behaviour = new BehaviorSubject(JSON.stringify(this.breakpoint));

    current_css = this.css_behaviour.asObservable();

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
        console.log();
        this.breakPointValue = window.innerWidth;
        console.log(this.breakPointValue);
        if (this.breakPointValue > 768) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.normal));
            this.css_behaviour.next(JSON.stringify(this.normal));
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.breakpoint));
            this.css_behaviour.next(JSON.stringify(this.breakpoint));
        }
    }

    public css() {
        if (this.breakPointValue > 768) {
            return this.normal;
        }
        return this.breakpoint;

    }

    constructor() { }
}
```

Is there any way to do this or this is incheavable from a service ?

Comment: I don't think you can use HostListener on service, try component/directive. ref: "Binds a CSS event to a host listener and supplies configuration metadata. Angular invokes the supplied handler method when the host element emits the specified event, and updates the bound element with the result. If the handler method returns false, applies preventDefault on the bound element."

Comment: demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8y2pg but you might want to check cross browser consistency

Comment: Silly question, but where are you initializing the service? You need to initialize it in a component. I will post an example below...

Comment: I will use a component and I beleive it wiser to use it on the root component then I will feed my service, this way my other component will subscribe and get the css
I will post my answer plz read it and tell me what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did not see in your OP where you are initializing the service. I had to do this almost exact thing in one app. We watch for screen size changes which triggers changes in some user preferences in local storage:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { TableViewTypes, MediaSizes, UserPreferencesDefaults, TableView, getTableViewDefaults } from '../models/user-preferences.model';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserPreferencesService {

    private tableViewSubject = new BehaviorSubject<TableView>(UserPreferencesDefaults.tableView);
    tableView$ = this.tableViewSubject.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private storageService: StorageService
    ) {}

    init() {
        this.tableViewSubject.next(
            !(window.outerWidth > MediaSizes.sm) ?
            getTableViewDefaults(false) :
            UserPreferencesDefaults.tableView
        );
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            this.tableViewSubject.next(
                !(window.outerWidth > MediaSizes.sm) ?
                getTableViewDefaults(false) :
                this.storageService.userPreferences.tableView
            );
        });
    }

    storeTableView(tableType: TableViewTypes, value: boolean) {
        this.storageService.userPreferences = {
            ...this.storageService.userPreferences,
            tableView: {
                ...this.storageService.userPreferences.tableView,
                [tableType]: value
            }
        };
    }

    toggleTableView(tableType: TableViewTypes, value?: boolean) {
        value = value !== undefined && value !== null ? value : !this.storageService.userPreferences.tableView[tableType];
        this.tableViewSubject.next({
            ...this.storageService.userPreferences.tableView,
            [tableType]: value
        });
        this.storeTableView(tableType, value);
    }

}
```

Then in order for the service to work it is initialized by injecting it into the app.component.ts in the constructor param

```
constructor(
    private userPreferenceService: UserPreferencesService,
) {this.userPreferenceService.init();}
```

Comment: updated my answer to call also this.userPreferenceService.init(); in the cunstructor

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check into Angular's Flex-Layout Package. You can inject its ObservableMedia service. Which will allow you to then subscribe to it a listen to window size changes.

```
    import {MediaChange, ObservableMedia} from '@angular/flex-layout';

    @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class BreakPointService {

     constructor(media: ObservableMedia) {}

     resize(){
      return this.media.pipe(map(change: MediaChange) => {
      //if changes doesn't have the width available on it, access it from the window object
      if (window.innerWidth > 768) {       
            return JSON.stringify(this.normal);
        } else {
            return JSON.stringify(this.breakpoint);
        }
      }));
     }
   }
```

will log the media change object to your console whenever you resize your window. After you subscribe to it in your component.

Comment: is all about the break point value in your code I can't see where you are getting the current screen width ?? !!!

Comment: You may have to access the window, and get the screen width manually. I'm not 100% if the MediaChange Object contains that or not. Although, I'm not sure why you shouldn't be able to go off the breakpoint or is there something specific about that screen size?

Comment: for the break point I choosed it randomly I only want to lear by my self

Comment: I updated the example to include, the window.InnerWidth, you could do this a little cleaner with a second map etc. but I hope this gets you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all replies.

I m still wanting to catch the resise event in the service, but thanks @ABOS and some tutorials about components communication, I got the Idea to use the root component to catch scren size event then to feed my service with changes in it observable, this way all subscribed component will get the breakpoint css values

no more talk here is my implementation

**app.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakPointService } from './providers/break-point.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'twithashWebApp';
    css_parent = '';
    breakPointValue: number;
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        BreakPointService.current_css.subscribe(value => {
            console.log('value is ' + value);
            this.css_parent = JSON.parse(value).css_parent;
        });
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
        console.log();
        this.breakPointValue = window.innerWidth;
        console.log(this.breakPointValue);
        if (this.breakPointValue > 768) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(BreakPointService.normal));
            BreakPointService.css_behaviour.next(JSON.stringify(BreakPointService.normal));
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(BreakPointService.breakpoint));
            BreakPointService.css_behaviour.next(JSON.stringify(BreakPointService.breakpoint));
        }
    }


}
```

**break-point.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BreakPointService {

    static normal = {
        background: 'w3-teal',
        inputColor: 'w3-light-grey',
        css_parent: 'w3-container w3-teal'
    };
    static breakpoint = {
        background: 'w3-dark-blue',
        inputColor: 'w3-white',
        css_parent: 'w3-container w3-light-grey'
    };


    static css_behaviour = new BehaviorSubject<string>(JSON.stringify(BreakPointService.breakpoint));

    static current_css = BreakPointService.css_behaviour.asObservable();



    constructor() { }
}
```

**corresponding template**

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div class="{{css_parent}}" style="text-align:center" style="height: 100%">
<app-tweet-list></app-tweet-list>
</div>
```