# Angular - Full calendar changing config based on screen width

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, angular6, window-resize

I am using Angular and Full Calendar. Is there any way to change to only enable list mode when the width of the screen is small?

HTML (This is where the config is used):

```
<div class="calendar-container">
  <angular2-fullcalendar #calendar [options]="calendarOptions" (initialized)="onCalendarInit($event)"></angular2-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

TS (This is where data to show is set along with setting the initial config in the ngOnInit):

```
calendarOptions: any;

ngOnInit() {

    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;

    //Set general calendar options
    this.calendarOptions = {
      //defaultView: 'listMonth'
      height:500,
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: false,
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
      },
      eventClick: (calEvent, jsEvent, view) => {
        //Open the dialog with event info
        this.openDialog(calEvent);
      }
    }
}

  onCalendarInit(e:boolean) {
    if(e) {

    this.subjectEventsService.subscribeToDataServiceGetSubjectEvents().subscribe(data=>{
        this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', data);
        this.eventsList = data;
      });
    }
  }
```

Note the `defaultView` option in the config, which when set to `listMonth`, will by default show the `listMonth` view which is the desired view when the screen is small. Along with this, I can remove the options to view other modes other than list in the `header` object.

However, I am not sure how to get the `angular2-fullcalendar` to update the config when the window is resized. I have tried to implement answers such as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350716/detect-window-size-using-angular-4), but to no avail. I have also tried to do something like:

```
<div class="calendar-container">
  <angular2-fullcalendar #calendar [options]="window.innerWidth > 768 ? calendarOptions : calendarOptionsSmall" (initialized)="onCalendarInit($event)"></angular2-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

Where `calendarOptionsSmall` is another config object with the desired config for a small screen, but, to no avail.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: see how I implemented this in my answer to this post....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688140/how-to-get-a-screen-resize-dimension-from-a-service-in-angular-2

Comment: Thanks for the implementation Sandra, I took a look, looks good, but, I found an easier way for my specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

After looking more closely at the FullCalendar doc, I realised there is an option to use `changeView` ([Doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/changeView)). Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350716/detect-window-size-using-angular-4/45350792), and then in the onResize() method, calling this:

```
if(this.innerWidth < 768){
    this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('changeView', 'listMonth');
}else{
    this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
}
```

With this I can change the view based on the width of the screen. You could take it a step further and customise the header options etc. Of course, this implementation is specific to FullCalendar.